# Compare two text files and write the non matching content in a third file

Tags: java

I have a requirement where I have to get a log file at some point of time - log_1.log and will take the same file after some time log_2.log with some new contents appended.

Now I have to compare both files and remove the matching content and get the non matching content and write it into a third file.

My intent is to get the logs recently appended in the file after I take the log for 1st time.

Comment: Please before question you should read how to put question here.if you aren't able to solve a specific problem, then put your code here, and ask for solution.here best of the best can answer your problem.so please put your code ask for solution. not the whole problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One possible method to start may be to convert file1 to a string and file 2 to a string.

Next use String functions within loops that if they find an extra character in string 2 will remove the extra char from String 2 and append the extra char to the 3rd file.

(Other algorithms exist)